# Which version of ubuntu for installing alongside windows 8 OR formatting windows without touching ubuntu 12.04 in its partition

Tags: 12.04, 13.04, dual-boot, partitioning, windows-8

I have windows 8 and ubuntu 12.04 installed alongside, within a partition each. Since I had upgraded from windows 7 after having installed ubuntu, I had no problem with the ubuntu installation back then. But, because of the upgrade, windows 8 works with a plethora of problems, and I want to format and install a clean version, maybe with 8.1. I want to keep the ubuntu partition as is, if possible, or I can format that as well and upgrade to 13.04, possibly. Which is the easier way to go, and what are the possible problems I might encounter?

Comment: After installing Windows 8, One of the problem is you will not able to access Ubuntu. Since Windows MBR deletes any entry of other MBR. So Ubuntu Grub will be overwritten by Windows, and there is no any grub menu as you get now. But this can be solved using Ubuntu LiveCD. Boot-repair can easily fix it.

Comment: So the easier path is to wipe win8 only, and then fix the grub. I mean, I'd rather do that, since it's gonna take hours for me to fix the keyboard shortcut, driver, mouse config issues, etc.

Comment: Yes you are right. But I suggest you to wipe Win8 partition using Gparted. It is best known tool for me.. And I also suggest you to use Win7, actually Win8 makes a lot of mess.. ;)

Comment: Can I just wipe it during the win8 install? While choosing the partition, right before the install? I guess I'll wait for 8.1 to decide which one runs more smoothly.

Comment: ha ha ha.. I hope so.. Hope Win8.1 is better than previous version. You should wait then. "Good things come to those who wait".